# How to optimally access the latest datapoint in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, time-series

I am storing multiple time-series in a MongoDB with sub-second granularity. The DB is updated by a bunch of Python scripts, and the data stored serve two main purposes:

**(1) It's a central information source for the latest data from all series.** Multiple scripts access it every second or so to read the latest datapoint in each collection.

**(2) It's a long-term data store.** I often load the whole DB into Python to analyse trends in the data.

To keep the DB as efficient as possible, **I want to bucket my data** (ideally holding one document per day in each collection). Because of (1), however, **the bigger the buckets, the more expensive the sorting required to access the last datapoint.**

I can think of two solutions here, but I'm not sure what alternatives there are, or which is the best way:

a) Store the latest timestamp in a one-line document in a separate db/collection. No sorting required on read, but an additional write required every time a any series gets a new datapoint.

b) Keep the buckets smaller (say 1-hour each) and sort.

Answer (score 0):

With a) you write smallish documents to a separate collection, which is performance wise preferable to updating large documents. You could write all new datapoints in this collection and aggregate them for the hour or day, depending on your preference. But as you said this requires an additional write operation.

With b) you need to keep the index size for the sort field in mind. Does the index size fit in memory? That's crucial for the performance of the sort, as you do not want to do any in memory sorting of a large collection.

I recommend exploring the hybrid approach, of storing individual datapoints for a limited time in an 'incoming' collection. Once your bucketing interval of hour or day approaches, you can aggregate the datapoints into buckets and store them in a different collection. Of course there is now some additional complexity in the application, that needs to be able to read bucketed and datapoint collections and merge them.